# Multiple nested unordered list items via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to Angular js and Firebase. I am developing an app which have multiple nested Unordered list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RGhW.png) , i need to save the data to firebase. and show it into fronted via angular's ng-repeat. how can i set it?
the code is look like

```
<ul>
<li>item 1
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3
            <ul>
                <li>item 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2
                            <ul>
                                <li>item 1</li>
                                <li>item 2</li>
                                <li>item 3
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>item 1
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>item 1</li>
                                                <li>item 2</li>
                                                <li>item 3</li>
                                                <li>item 4</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>item 2</li>
                                        <li>item 3</li>
                                        <li>item 4</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>item 4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                        <li>item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
                <li>item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3
            <ul>
                <li>item 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                        <li>item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
                <li>item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>item 4</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Directives` to achieve this. Let me give you basic direction and then you can do it on your own.

Structure of the data array should be like

```
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1', items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Item 1'},
        { id: 1, name: 'Item 2', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}]},
        { id: 1, name: 'Item 3', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}, { id: 1, name: 'Item 2'}]}
    ]},
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 2'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 3', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}]},
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 4'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 5', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}, { id: 1, name: 'Item 2'}]}
];
```

Create an `Angular Directive`

```
app.directive('listItems', function(){ 
 return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   scope: {
    source: '='
   },
   template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in data" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} <list-items data="item.items" ng-if="item.items"></list-items> </li></ul>'
 }
});
```

Note: The template is self embedding the next list based on `items` in the object, see `ng-if` condition

A working snippet
[Code pen working example](http://codepen.io/farooqkhan/pen/EZbNwg)

Comment: Thankyou so much.. i loved your answer. :)

Comment: You are welcome. It would be nice if you accept it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to nest your data, something like this:

```
$scope.data = [{data:[...],nest1:[{data2:[...],nest2:[{data3:[...]}]}]}]...
```

and you can go down as much as you won't.

Now for the angular.

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in data">
  <li>{d.data}</li>
    <ul ng-repeat="nest1 in d">
     <li>{nest1.data2}</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

you need to specify you data and ng-repeat do the rest for you.